# Modificar una tabla ya existente a través de migraciones usando Lavarel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5, migration

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación usando `Laravel`, y dado que cambiaron algunos requerimientos necesito agregar una nueva a columna a una tabla ya existente, sí bien podría hacerlo a conectándome a través de la base de datos, leí en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#modifying-columns) de `Laravel` que es posible hacerlo a través del método `table` del objeto `Schema`, como por ejemplo

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('field')
});
```

Sin embargo cuando ejecuto el comando `php artisan migrate`, no suceden nada ni siquiera un error, y la tabla sigue igual. Este es el código de la migración de el método `up` que ejecuta las migraciones:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tablename', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('something_id');
            $table->string('name', 64);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

      Schema::table('tablename', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('othercolumn', 64)->nullable();
      });
    }
```

**Lo que no entiendo, es que como hacerlo.**